# Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 2 Unable to see details of stack information after crash

Tags: c++, crash, android-studio-2.1

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U41qx.png)
this is not what I want to see.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zB7zp.png)
I want to see traceable stack information.
Debugging Android native code sometimes fails to see detailed stack information after crashing, making it difficult to locate bugs.